# 透過させたPyQtダイアログの背面にある、別アプリを操作したい

Tags: python, pyqt

GUIを初学から最近はじめました。

透け紙アプリのようなイメージで、透過ウィンドウをとあるアプリケーションのウィンドウに重ね、透過ウィンドウを前面にしたまま、透過先のそのアプリケーションをマウスで操作したいと思っています。

現在、PyQtのダイアログを透過させてチャレンジしています。
PyQt上で解決するべきか、Windows(11)の操作・設定で解決できるものかもわからず困っています。

ヒットしやすい検索ワードだけでもいいので、教えて頂けたら助かります。

Comment: この記事が該当しそうな感じです。[How to set QWindow to be transparent to mouse and other events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69315605/9014308) こちらの記事も関連しそうな感じですが、もしかしたら目的は逆かもしれません。[Is there any way to make mouse events completely ignore windows in PyQt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65167075/9014308), [PyQt: eventFilter to get mouse position in a semi-transparent window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25340526/9014308), [How to create a semi transparent window in WPF that allows mouse events to pass through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2842667/9014308)

Comment: 過不足なく、問題が解決できました。ありがとうございます！冒頭の記事を参考にsetWindowFlagsでQt.WindowTransparentForInput | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint を指定することで、半透明なQt Windowを前面に置いたまま、透過先の別アプリを操作することができました。

Comment: 解決したならその内容を情報共有のために、出来れば該当機能だけでも試せる程度に完結したサンプルコードも含めて、自己回答してみてください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

kunif様コメント冒頭の記事を参考に、以下のコードで半透明ウィンドウを前面に出したまま、うしろの別アプリを操作できました。

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()

#set parameter and flags to overlay on another window
window.setWindowOpacity(0.5)
window.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowTransparentForInput | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```